# Here API Request Per Second limits

Tags: here-api

I'm testing out the Here API for geocoding purposes. Currently in the evaluation period, some of my tests include geocoding as many as 400 addresses at a time (later I may rarely hit 1000). When I tried this with google maps, they would give me an error indicating I'd gone over the rate limit, but I have not gotten such an error from Here API despite not limiting the rate of my requests (beyond waiting for one to finish before sending the next).

But in the [Developer FAQ](https://developer.here.com/faqs) the Requests Per Second limit is given as:

```
            Public Plans    Business Plans
Basic       1               N/A
Starter     1               1
Standard    2               2
Pro         3               3
```

Which seems ridiculously slow. 1 request per second? 3 per second on the highest plan? Is this chart a typo? If so, what are the actual limits? If not, what kind of error should I expect if I exceed that limit?

Comment: Update from 2020: there seems to be no limitation mentioned in their documentation about usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their documentation states that the RPS means "for each Application the number of Requests per second to HERE Services calculated as an average (number of Requests during a period of 5 minutes) to all of the APIs used to access the features listed for each subscription plan".*

They say later in the documentation that quota is calculated monthly: "When a usage record is loaded into our billing system that results in a plan crossing its monthly quota, the price applied to that usage record is pro-rated to account for the portion that is included in your monthly quota for free and the portion that is billable. Subsequent usage records above your monthly quota will show at the per transaction prices listed on this website."*

Overages are billed at 200/$1 USD for Business or 2000/$1 USD for Public plans. So for the Pro plan, you will hit your limit if you use more than 7.779 million API requests in any given month, any usage beyond that would be billed at the rates above.

- Excerpts taken from Developer FAQ linked above.

Comment: I believe the quota is referring to total requests; I haven't seen anything relating the quota to the rate at which requests come in.

Comment: You're right, sorry! I missed the monthly quota of 15K for Public, or 50K - 150K for Business (based on selection at https://developer.here.com/plans). So the monthly quota and overages are billed at that, which would make me believe that the rate limiting would be calculated off of the 5-minute average (300 - 900 transactions per 5 minutes based on the 1 - 3 RPS levels). Does your application exceed 300 requests in 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too, but when I geocode 400 addresses in one go, it takes at most a minute, with no errors for over rate. If I get several users of my application and a few of them need to geocode at the same time, I could easily go over 900 in five minutes (though not often).

Comment: Are you using the batch geocoding API? I was looking at the transaction usage on https://developer.here.com/plans and they define it as "For most of our services, a transaction is one server request. For map, satellite and traffic tiles, it's 15 requests." I don't see anything indicating that a batch geocode request (with "up to a million lines of address information") is more than a single request. So if you are batching those 400 addresses, it looks to me like that would be a single transaction per batch. That surprises me, but that is what the documentation leads me to believe.

Comment: I wasn't, then I tried, and I'm getting a 403. The error makes it seem like the batch geocoding API isn't available on the trial license, despite documentation which suggests otherwise. I've emailed them directly to ask for clarification on that point, but my original question is still relevant.

Comment: @ChrisTyler Did they answered your email? I'm getting the same 403 error on "Freemium" plan and wonder what plan should  allow me to use a batch geocoding.